# unable to upgrade .NET framework 4

Tags: windows, .net-framework

Upgrade for the Jabra Desktop client on Windows 7 32bit fails because of .NET 4

There is a [discussion on msdn](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/is/synctoy/thread/0633a1e3-2234-4f82-911a-712b258ed29c) with an error similar to mine but without any resolution. The error says - Process exited with code -2146762485

Hopefully, someone in this community will be able to help me get past this error.

Error Log

```
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)', phase BeforePackage
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client'
Unable to read registry value
Not setting value for property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)':
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' was not defined
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '5.1.2': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'IA64': false
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' is 'Install'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: Install Needed
Verifying file integrity of C:\Users\aname~1.ST-\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5210.tmp\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe
WinVerifyTrust returned 0
File trusted
Installing using command 'C:\Users\aname~1.ST-\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5210.tmp\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' and parameters ' /q /norestart /ChainingPackage ClientX64ClickOnce /lcid 1033'
Process exited with code -2146762485
Status of package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' after install is 'InstallFailed'
```

Solutions Tried

1. Disabled the firewall and proxy. .NET 4 was downloaded fine but, the install still failed with the same error code.

Comment: What OS? Did you try jsut reinstalling the machine?

Comment: As mentioned in the question, it is Windows 7 32bit and NO, I will NOT re-install the machine. I will move to a Mac, before re-installing Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The error number -2146762485 appears to be a certificate failure - It's like it's trying to check the signature on the installation file and failing. Is the machine properly connected to the internet/does it have a firewall running?

Comment: Disabled the firewall and proxy. .NET 4 was downloaded fine as it did before but, the install still fails with the same error code.